# Trying to run Sikuli from Python 3.5.4 within Anaconda using Spyder IDE

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, spyder, sikuli

I get "*AttributeError: module 'sikuli' has no attribute 'sikuli'* " error when trying to run Sikuli from Python 3.5.4 IDE.  I understand I should use Jython but I want to use Python.

I used "pip install sikuli" and that installed version .1 of Sikuli along with following packages without any error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: sikuli in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: jnius>=1.1-dev in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sikuli)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jnius>=1.1-dev->sikuli)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jnius>=1.1-dev->sikuli)
```

This is my code:

```
import sikuli as sk
sk.sikuli.click("image.png")
```

Running above code throws following error: AttributeError: module 'Skuli' has no attribute 'Sikuli'

I know Sikuli installed fine because when I press tab (period) it autocomplete with Sikuli commands.

Any help greatly appreciated. I am new to Python.

Thanks
Sean